# "Это был Сидоров" - что здесь "это"?

Tags: грамматика

Задумался. 
**У**: Дети, кто написал на доске плохое слово?

**А**: Это [был] Сидоров!  
**Б**: Это Сидоров был! 
**В**: Это Сидоров написал!  
**Г**: Сидоров это написал!
**Д**: Сидоров написал это!

Чем в этих случаях является "это"? Если усилительная частица (по Кузнецову), то что она усиливает?

Answer (score 2):

А: Это [был] Сидоров! - это - подлежащее, выраженное указательным местоимением =то, о чём говорилось в предыдущем предложении. был Сидоров - сказуемое (есть Сидоров).

Б: Это Сидоров был! - то же самое с инверсией глагола-связки был.

В: Это Сидоров написал! - может быть понято двояко: Сидоров написал что? - это (плохое слово)-дополнение. Неполное с пропуском "плохое слово": Это Сидоров написал (плохое слово)!-это уже не дополнение, это частица для указания на мысль, содержащуюся в предыдущем предложении. Например: Вчера сосед заходил, спрашивал тебя. - Это Сидоров что ли?

Г: Сидоров это написал! - то же самое.

Д: Сидоров написал это! - то же самое.

Как частица ЭТО употребляется

1. Для подчёркивания, выделения того члена предложения, перед которым находится: "Это вы только верите, а я нет".
2. Для указания на мысль в предыдущем предложении.
3. В вопросительном предложении для усиления вопросительного местоимения или наречия: Куда это вы собрались?
4. Для выделения слова, ПОСЛЕ которого находится - для плавности речи: Иду это я вчера...
5. В школьной программе частицей считается и связка ЭТО в СИС: Доказать - это убедить.

Comment: Людмила, мы уже это с вами как-то обсуждали, немного на другмх вещах... 
Хорошо, что Вы  написалм "можно понять двояко", я очень тогда долго бился, чтобы это услышать... Плохо, что вы ограничили это только одним пунктом.   
Непонятно: 
Почему в А. "это" не может быть частицей? По тем же мотивам, что в В. 
Если в А. "это" подлежащее (и указательное местоимение), то какое почему сказуемое не согласуется с ним в грамматическом роде? А Сидоровым - согласуется?

Comment: Строго говоря, связь между подлежащим и сказуемым не согласование, а координация(согласование+управление, взаимная связь по смыслу). В СИС согласование происходит не только между подлежащим и связкой, но и между подлежащим и именной частью. Как правило, связка согласуется с подлежащим в том же роде и числе, падеж может и не совпасть (связка может быть в творительном падеже): Ариэль была любимица(любимицей) всех родных. Разочарование ведьмы было ужасным. Возможно согласование связки в СИС не с подлежащим, а с самой именной частью: Свадьба Ариэль было самое радостное событие в семье.

Comment: "Это " включает в себя любое событие, оно ассоциируется со словом любого рода.В данном случае ЭТО-"ТОТ, кто..." или "нарушитель"-ассоциация со словом муж. рода.Координация это допускает.

Answer (score 1):

А, Б. Это - подлежащее, а вот часть речи... не знаю. Частица может быть подлежащим? Вряд ли.

В, Г, Д. Это - дополнение, выраженное местоименным существительным. Либо же здесь "это" - усилительная частица. Но в примере Д частицей выглядит коряво, так не говорят. Поэтому - мест.сущ., дополнение.

А-а, что усиливает? Сидорова, видимо, усиливает. ))

— Эт-то что такое?! Кто написал?

— [Да] [это] Сидоров написал! [Это] не я!

По-моему, как-то так.

P.S. Нет, по поводу А и Б большие сомнения...

Comment: Ну я ж специально набросал серию примеров. Чтобы сбить спесь с самоуверенных знатоков вопросом, где кончается частица и где начинается местоимение в роли дополнения.

>Но в примере Д частицей выглядит коряво    
      
Ну что вы... "Да Сидоров был это, зуб даю." Что "был", что "написал" - разница тут небольшая. Просто при переходном глаголе воспринимается в первую очередь как дополнение. Написал - что? Потому и выглядит коряво. Я это тоже имел в виду.

Comment: Все-таки разве в А "это" не может быть подлежащим?

Comment: А здесь у "это" и нету рода. *Это моя мама. Это мой папа.* Здесь точно подлежащее. Можно и тире поставить, чтоб совсем уж никаких сомнений. )))

Comment: >А здесь у "это" и нету рода   
  
Так не бывает... см. Кузнецова. У местоимений есть род. Вот у частицы его, конечно, нет. Но частица не подлежащее. 

>Это мой папа.   
  
Это [есть] мой папа. Это [есть] моя мама. > Это был мой папа. Это была моя мама.   
  
Ни о чем не говорит? )))  
Ну ладно, допустим у подлежащего "нет рода" (допустим!!!), но почему тогда сказуемое согласуется в роде с дополнением?  
Где-то мы с Людмилой на эту тему уже спорили...  
(+)  
Сидоров был моя мама... Сидоров была моя мама?  
Не, это что-то фантасмагорическое.

Comment: >> но почему тогда сказуемое согласуется в роде с дополнением?

Выходит, что папа и мама — именное сказуемое.

А у Кузнецова и вообще нет примера типа "Это мой папа".

Comment: А именное сказуемое согласуется в роде с подлежащим а не с именной частью.  
Ио-то и оно, что Кузнецова вообще нет примеров с "Это" в подобной функции. Что есть - не подходят.

Comment: У Ожегова:
...
4. сущ. **это** -ого, ср.
То (тот), о чем (о ком) идет речь, что (кто) находится перед говорящим.
Э. был незнакомец. Как всё э. случилось?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, при поиске функции слова в сокращённом ответе на вопрос исходить нужно из прямого и полного ответа на него. "Был" из другого вопроса:

- Кто стоял у доски?
- Сидоров.
- Это был Сидоров.

В нашем случае "был" для ответа не подходит:

- Кто написал слово?
- Сидоров.
- Это сделал Сидоров. (полный ответ; прямое дополнение)
- Это Сидоров. (краткий ответ на вопрос: "кто" (злоумышленник)?; подлежащее)

Comment: >> Это Сидоров. (краткий ответ на вопрос: "кто" (злоумышленник)?; подлежащее)

Нет, в этом случае частица.

*– А кто это?

– Это Сидоров.*

Вот здесь – указательное слово, подлежащее.

Comment: - Кто же это (, тот написавший слово ученик)?
- Это(т ученик есть) Сидоров.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что правильным будет такой вариант:

1) Указательная частица:  Это Сидоров!   Это Сидоров написал! (В этом случае слово "это" можно изъять из предложения: Кто написал? - Сидоров.

2) Местоимение в роли дополнения:  Сидоров это написал! Сидоров написал это!  (местоимение "это" заменяет "плохое слово").

3) Это Сидоров был!   Этот вариант для данной ситуации не подходит.